# Passing props to modal passes every object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-props

I'm not 100% sure what's going on here. I've got a display component that displays a bunch of cards, using a map based on my database  - On the card is an edit button that pops a modal up, passing props over to the edit form.. Here's kinda how it looks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/client'

import { GET_ALL_PROJECTS, REMOVE_PROJECT } from '../helpers/queries'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete'
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit'
import AddForm from './AddForm'
import EditForm from './EditForm'
import AlertMessage from '../Alerts/AlertMessage'
import { Grid, Typography, Card, CardActionArea, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Modal, Backdrop, Fade } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));


const DisplayProjects = () => {

  const styles = useStyles()

  const [deleteItem] = useMutation(REMOVE_PROJECT)
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_PROJECTS)
  const [status, setStatusBase] = useState('')
  const [resultMessage, setResultMessage] = useState('')
  const [addOpen, setAddOpen] = useState(false)
  const [editOpen, setEditOpen] = useState(false)

  const onDelete = (id, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    deleteItem({
      variables: { id },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_ALL_PROJECTS }]
    }).then(
      res => handleSuccess(res),
      err => handleError(err)
    )

  }

  // Handles Result of the Delete Operation
  const handleSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log(res.data.deleteProject.proj_name)
    // console.log('success!');
    setResultMessage(res.data.deleteProject.proj_name)
    setStatusBase({
      msg: `Successfully Deleted ${resultMessage}`,
      key: Math.random()
    })
  }
  const handleError = (err) => {
    console.log('error')
  }

  //Handles the Modal for Add Project
  const handleAddOpen = () => {
    setAddOpen(true);
  };
  const handleAddClose = () => {
    setAddOpen(false);
  };

//Handles the Modal for Edit Project
  const handleEditOpen = () => {
    setEditOpen(true);
  };
  const handleEditClose = () => {
    setEditOpen(false);
  };


  if (loading) return '...Loading'
  if (error) return `Error: ${error.message}`
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={8} justify='center' alignItems='center'>
          {data.projects.map(p => {
            return (
              <Grid item key={p._id}>
                <Card >
                  <CardActionArea>
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                      <CardMedia
                        style={{ width: 400, height: 100, paddingTop: 10, }}
                        component='img'
                        alt='Project Image'
                        height='140'
                        image={require('../../images/html-css-javascript-lg.jpg')}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <CardContent >
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component="h2">
                        {p.proj_name}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography component='p'>
                        {p.description}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </CardActionArea>
                  <CardActions>
                    <Button>
                      <DeleteIcon onClick={e => onDelete(p._id, e)} />
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleEditOpen}>
                      <Modal
                        open={editOpen}
                        onClose={handleEditClose}
                        closeAfterTransition
                        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                        className={styles.modal}
                      >
                        <Fade in={editOpen}>
                          <div className={styles.paper}>
                            <EditForm
                              id={p._id}
                              close={handleEditClose}
                              name={p.proj_name}
                              desc={p.description}
                              gh={p.gh_link}
                              live={p.live_link}
                              img={p.image_url}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </Fade>
                      </Modal>
                      <EditIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
                { status ? <AlertMessage key={status.key} message={status.msg} /> : null}
              </Grid>
            )
          }
          )}

        </Grid>
        <Button type='button' onClick={handleAddOpen}>Add Project</Button>
        <Modal
          open={addOpen}
          onClose={handleAddClose}
          closeAfterTransition
          BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
          className={styles.modal}
        >
          <Fade in={addOpen}>
            <div className={styles.paper}>
              <AddForm close={handleAddClose} />
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </Modal>



      </div>
    </div >
  )
}

export default DisplayProjects
```

And here's the form. I've destructured out the props into variables and placed them into a state object called details, so they can be overwritten and submitted to the database..

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { EDIT_PROJECT, GET_ALL_PROJECTS, GET_PROJECT_BY_ID} from '../helpers/queries'


const AddForm = (props) => {
  const params = useParams()
  const id = params.toString()
  // console.log(id);
  const [editProjectItem] = useMutation(EDIT_PROJECT)
  const {loading, data, error} = useQuery(GET_PROJECT_BY_ID, {
        variables: {
        id
      },
    })

  const [details, setDetails] = useState({})


  if (loading) return '...Loading';
  if (error) return <p>ERROR: {error.message}</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;
  setDetails(data.projectById)
  console.log(data.projectById)


  
  const submitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
    editProjectItem({
      variables: { id, proj_name, description, gh_link, live_link, image_url},
      refetchQueries: [{query: GET_ALL_PROJECTS}]
    })
  }
  catch (err) {
        console.log('You Goofed')
    }

    // setDetails({
    //   proj_name: '',
    //   description: '',
    //   gh_link: '',
    //   live_link: '',
    //   image_url: ''
    // })
    props.close()
  }

  const changeDetails = (e) => {
    setDetails({
      ...details,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  const {_id, proj_name, description, gh_link, live_link, image_url} = details

  return (
    <div key = {_id}>

      <h2>Edit {proj_name}</h2>

      <form onSubmit = {submitForm} >

      <label>
        Project Name:
        <input
          name = 'proj_name'
          value = {proj_name}
          onChange = {changeDetails}
          />
        </label>
      <label>Description</label>
      <input
        name = 'description'
        value = {description}
        onChange = {changeDetails}
        />
        <label>GitHub Link</label>
      <input
        name  = 'gh_link'
        value = {gh_link}
        onChange = {changeDetails}
        />
        <label>Live Link</label>
      <input
        name = 'live_link'
        value = {live_link}
        onChange = {changeDetails}
        />
        <label>Preview Image</label>
      <input
        name = 'image_url'
        value = {image_url}
        onChange = {changeDetails}
        />
        <button type = 'submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
  }

export default AddForm
```

The problem I'm running into, is that when I access the modal, the props are sent from literally EVERY Object, instead of the one, and displays the data for the last record instead of the one I want to edit You can see what happens here (I logged props.id in order to test) https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJc5P.jpg

What did I miss? (Disclaimer: I am still a student, and learning the craft.. be gentle on my code please)

EDIT: I just realized that I didn't indicate that this is the final form of the EditForm component. I haven't added the logic in to make the updates yet, I just wanted to get the data showing properly first.

EDIT2: I made some changes to how the ID is passed over, I was already using React-Router, so I went ahead and made a route to /edit/:id and then using useParams(), I got the ID that way. It seems to be working, however now I'm getting a Too many re-renders message. Updated the AddForm code above to reflect the changes..

Comment: Please include code where you mapped the data to create the cards? The code you provided doesn't tell much about the behavior you’re describing, because I’m assuming that ‘p’’ is an item of ‘.map()’

Comment: Can you share the code for the handle edit open function?

Comment: Yep, I'll edit the post and add the whole component if that helps.. Keep in mind it's a Apollo/GraphQL implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the re-render issue.. it was as simple as dropping the setDetails function into a useEffect Hook:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if(data){
      setDetails(data.projectById)
    }
  },[data])
```